# using while to check if input is in range python3

Tags: python

beginner alert. This is my tictactoe code and i can not find the problem when I am trying to check whether player entered playable value (1-9). Thanks for help.

```
   # the player now inserts input (coordinates of the field where he want his symbol written)
    print('Player', p, ', go! Enter the position that you want to play.')
    i = input()
    i = int(i) - 1

    while i in range(10,99):
        print('entered number does not match any position in the game, try again')
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: replace while with for.

Comment: You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if i not in range(1,10): 
  print("Invalid entry")
```

You should use an if statement